# in R, how to pass name of a function to another function as an input

Tags: r, function

In R, how can I pass function name as an input to function caller procedure. Let say I have functions func1(), func2(), func3(), ...., func100().
a caller function takes the input; name of the function and runs it (not using if statement).

```
 function_caller=function(func_name){
    
    #if func_name is func1 then func1 should be executed.
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since functions are also objects, you can add a parameter for the function. Use `...` to add the parameters of `f` without explicitly calling them (since they might be different between functions).

```r
f1 <- function(x) sum(x)
function_caller <- function(func_name, ...) func_name(...)

function_caller(f1, x = 1:2)
#[1] 3
```